# Setting color key to a numerical range

Tags: r

I generated heatmap using `heatmap.2` function in R and tried to make two modifications

1. The colour key scale need to range 5,10,15. However, I could not set that range for the scale by changing the following line,

   ```
   colors = c(seq(0,5,length=100), seq(5,10,length=100), seq(10,15,length=100))
   ```
2. Number (like 1, 2 3 upto the total number of rows) is shown to the end of each row and I could not delete it.

So, I look forward any suggestion to set the scale and remove  the numbered Y-axis.

```
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)
dat <- read.csv("C:/Users/anikng/Desktop/stress.csv")
dat_matrix <- data.matrix(dat)
colors = c(seq(0,5,length=100),seq(5,10,length=100),seq(10,15,length=100))
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"))(n = 299)
heatmap.2(dat_matrix, dendrogram="none", Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, col = my_palette,     breaks=colors, scale="none", key=TRUE, density.info="none", trace="none", symm=F,symkey=T,symbreaks=T)
```

Comment: Regarding part a - Do you mean that you want a colormap with three levels and the breaks should be at 5,10,15 ?

Comment: es, I set 300 breaks and ultimately the displayed color range should be in the range 5,10,15. I am searching for color key like here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048543/r-centering-heatmap-2-key-gplots-package]  (instead of -5.0,5 it should be 5,10,15) :@csgillespie

Answer (score 1):

When asking a question it's always easier if you can provide some example data, so

```
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)
dat_matrix= matrix(rnorm(1000, 10, 3), ncol=10)
```

1. The issue with the range in the symkey was caused by the `symkey=TRUE` argument. Removing that argument, your code now works

   ```
   breaks = c(seq(min(dat_matrix), median(dat_matrix), length.out=128), 
      seq(median(dat_matrix), max(dat_matrix), length.out=128))

   heatmap.2(dat_matrix, dendrogram="none", Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, breaks=breaks, 
            key=TRUE, density.info="none", trace="none", col=my_palette)
   ```
2. To remove the numbers from the graph, add the arguments: `labRow=FALSE` and `labCol=FALSE`